# Yii2 create audit record by passing old and newly updated record and comparing the data

Tags: yii2, audit

I'm trying to create a `create audit` method that I can use with other model. The logic I'm using is to pass the old record before `submit` from form and `save()` in the model occur. And pass the newly updated data after 'save()'. I check the `contentBefore` data before 'post' request and I'm getting the old record. But after 'save()' contentBefore data gets updated with the newly updated data which is not obviously what I want.

Can someone suggest a better method or find the error in my code?

Thank you!

Here is the code in update action of a model

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    // get the old data before update
    $contentBefore = $model;
    // If I var_dump('contentBefore') here I get the old data

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  $model->save()) {

        // get the newly updated data and pass it to 'createaudit'
        $contentAfter = $model;
        $tableName = $model->formName();
        $operation = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;

        // Here var_dump($contentBefore) I get the newly updated data 
        AuditTrialController::Createaudit($contentBefore, $contentAfter, $tableName, $operation);

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my create audit code in AuditTrialController

```
public static function Createaudit($contentBefore, $contentAfter, $tableName, $operation)
{

    $model = new AuditTrial();

    $model->old = '';
    $model->new = '';

    foreach($contentBefore as $name => $value){
        $tempOne = $name .': '. $value.',  ';
        $before[] = $tempOne;
    } 

    foreach($contentAfter as $name => $value){
        $tempTwo = $name .': '. $value.',  ';
        $after[] = $tempTwo;
    } 

    $length = count($after);
    for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
        if ( $before[$x] != $after[$x] ) {
           $model->old = $model->old.' '.$before[$x];
           $model->new = $model->new.' '.$after[$x];
       }
    } 

    $model->modified_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
    $model->operation = $operation;
    $model->date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a');
    $model->table_name = $tableName;
    $model->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first read this about PHP [Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) :

> As of PHP5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.

This simply means `$contentBefore` and `$contentAfter` are the same...

A simple workaround could be to use [$attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#$attributes-detail), e.g. :

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
$oldAttributes = $model->attributes;
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  $model->save()) {
    $newAttributes = $model->attributes;
    $tableName = $model->formName();
    $operation = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
    AuditTrialController::Createaudit($oldAttributes, $newAttributes, $tableName, $operation);
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

And an alternative solution could be to use [Dirty Attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#dirty-attributes) (but the comparison of old and new values will be done using the `===`).

Answer (score -1):

I've solved my problem. Thanks to Soju for pointing out my mistake. I'm getting the `$contentBefore` and `$contentAfter` value through active record. This is working for me. If I need to improve my code, please do let me know.

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    // get the old data before update 
    $modelname = get_class($model); // updated part
    $contentBefore = $modelname::findOne($id); // updated part

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  $model->save()) {

        // get the newly updated data and pass it to 'createaudit'
       $contentAfter = $modelname::findOne($id); // updated part
       $tableName = $model->formName();
       $operation = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;

       AuditTrialController::Createaudit($contentBefore, $contentAfter, $tableName, $operation);

       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);   
    }

 }
```

Comment: Yes you really need a better code... Did you try mine ?

Comment: Are you talking about using [dirty attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#dirty-attributes)?